# One pixate stylesheet per view controller?

Tags: ios, pixate

It looks like things are set up to have just one stylesheet (default.css) for the entire application. Is there any way to have a stylesheet per view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS, you can use the `@import` tag in case you wish to organize your CSS better.
The Android version, unfortunately, is lacking this support due to a bug and I hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: That would have to be imported from default.css though?

Comment: Yes. You will still need the default.css as a connecting point.

Comment: I see what you're saying. default.css @imports css files for each screen. I was hoping there was a way to have each screen load its own css file.

Comment: Any updates about having @import working on Android?